# How can a 501(c)(3) nonprofit require "members" to pay "dues"?

Tags: united-states, non-profit

United States here. Lots of 501(c)(3) organizations, such as the Boy Scouts of America, charge their members monthly and/or annual dues.

My *understanding* was that the only nonprofits that can have "due-paying members" are 501(c)(7) **social clubs**. Is this not the case, or is there a loophole somewhere that allows 501(c)(3) orgs to have due-paying members?